# HTTP response 403 when program tries to initiate connection to Google?

Tags: java, web-crawler, httpurlconnection

I have written a test web crawler class that attempts to search Google, as shown:

```
public class WebCrawler {
String query;

public WebCrawler(String search)
{
    query = search;
}

public void connect()
{
    HttpURLConnection connection = null;
    try 
    {
        String url = "http://www.google.com/search?q=" + query;
        URL search = new URL(url);

        connection = (HttpURLConnection)search.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.setUseCaches(false);
        connection.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
        connection.connect();

        BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
        String line = null;
        while((line = read.readLine())!=null)
        {
            System.out.println(line);
        }

        read.close();
    }

    catch(MalformedURLException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch(ProtocolException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally
    {
        connection.disconnect();
    }
}
```

}

When I try to run it with a test query "test" though, I get a HTTP response 403 error-- what am I missing? This is my first time doing any networking stuff with Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

403 == forbidden, which makes sense because you're a robot trying to access a part of google that they don't want robots accessing.  [Google's robots.txt](http://www.google.com/robots.txt) pretty clearly specifies that you shouldn't be scraping /search.

Google provides a [search API](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/overview) which allows 100 queries per day.  They provide [libraries](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/libraries) and examples of how to interface with it in most languages, including Java.  More than that, you've gotta pay.

Comment: You could just change the `User-Agent` header.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I'm perfectly aware there's ways to sidestep robot detection.  Those things will only get you so far, Google does other filtering.

Comment: OP possibly didn't know.